# Access web server behind OpenVPN client

Tags: vpn, proxy, openvpn, webserver, nginx

Okay so:

- I have a machine running an OpenVPN client (it's connecting to a server elsewhere, the machine does not act as the server)
- The machine also has an Nginx web server
- When the OpenVPN client is disconnected, my web server is accessible externally and internally (as desired)
- When the OpenVPN client is connected, my web server is accessible only internally

  - Oddly it can still be accessed over its FQDN so I presume there's some weird internal DNS loopback caching happening? How does this work?

I would like all outgoing traffic to be forwarded through the VPN, or to exclude Nginx from the VPN.

Is this at all possible? How would I achieve this?

Comment: What OS and router setup? The abreviated answer is to do policy based routing on the device with the VPN client so that traffic to/from the web server (at least on port 80/443) goes through a different route table which does not have the VPN as a default gateway.

Comment: Ubuntu server, the router is a Sky Hub so nothing fancy at all. I'll look into that and report back if I get something working, cheers.

Comment: Where is the OpenVPN client running?  (Ubuntu or Sky Hub?)

Comment: Ubuntu. Should have specified that, sorry. The hub does nothing more than basic home firewall and port forwarding (plus acting as a router...).

Comment: you connect to the vpn server because you want to route your traffic thru it? because thats what seems to happen here.

Comment: Yes, that is what's happening. I only partially wanted that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there are other similar solutions, but I managed to fix this by routing traffic through another web server, which reverse-proxied the request to the server connected to OpenVPN.